# Scrape Grafana for dashboards that haven't been viewed in X amount in time

Tags: grafana

I'm trying to figure out how to scrape grafana via its API to pull all dashboards that haven't been viewed in over a year, so we can then delete them. I've only ever scraped a website, so this is new to me.

Anyone ever do this before, or done something similar? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Grafana API doesn't provide details, when dashboard was viewed. So that's really not a task for the Grafana API (in your meaning curl scraping). It is a task for your Grafana logs analytics. You will need to merge usage details based on Grafana logs (or reverse proxy access logs eventualy) analysis with the dashboard list, so you will get desired result. You need to be prepared with good logs for this kind of analytics in advance.

BTW: Grafana enterprise provides [Usage insights](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/enterprise/usage-insights/), but those data are also not exposed via API